# Selecting Column

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I have a table in sheet1 in cell range G3:M8, I am writing a macro to select column G3, getting the error

> Run-time error 9, subscript out of range

What is wrong with the below code?

```
Sub selectcolumn()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("G3: M8").ListColumns(1).Range.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put the name (or index) of the table in quotes, not the address string.

Comment: Why do you want to `Select` the range, anyway? It is rarely necessary, and can sometimes lead to problems.

Comment: why not trying `columns('G').select`

Comment: @SJR, yes the table name is mytable, initially I was trying that but was getting the same error.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I am new learner, I was trying to see the functionality of "ListObjects" and how it works.

Comment: @Anabas just trying to understand the functionality of "ListObjects" and how it works.

Comment: @SNEHA maybe this [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) will help you, with all its methods and properties.

Comment: Thanks it is of great help.